# Image cover inside slider

Tags: css, image, slider, cover

I have the following bootstrap slider

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have images with different height, how can I use the cover function to get all images same height and width fit to border and with a cover center effect ?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Comment: you need to set image in background....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="100%" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: 50% 50%; height: 60vh">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="100%" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: 50% 50%; height: 60vh">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="100%" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: 50% 50%; height: 60vh">
    </div>
   </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
 </div>
```

Note: object-git don't work on IE and object-position center center don't work on all browser